# iOS simulator -- get rid of the "reset/don't reset" window?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, simulator

I reset my simulator often and find that window annoying.  Is there any way I can permanently get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

Write a quick applescript/automator action which trashes the appropriate folder:
I think it's: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator

Then just run that from the dock or from the script menu